# Use a button for two functions -- show content, and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 form, that is shown using it's `collapse()` function on a `<button>` element.
I would then, once the form is open, have this same button become the submit button on the form.
However, I have no idea how to change a button's function on *second press*.

Example code:

```
<form class="collapse" id="1234">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1234">Open Form</button>
```

jQuery function ready for code:

```
$(".btn-block").click(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "Open Form") {
        $(this).text("Submit Form");
    } else {
        $(this).text("Open Form");
    }
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle with the toggle in action: http://jsfiddle.net/tzosozwv/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Call `submit()` on your `form` element within your `if` statement:

```
if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "Open Form") {
    $(this).text("Submit Form");
} else {
    // Presumably this is where you want your form submitted...
    $('form#1234').submit();
    $(this).text("Open Form");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a submit

```
$(".btn-block").click(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "Open Form") {
        $(this).text("Submit Form");
    } else {
        $('#1234').submit();
        $(this).text("Open Form");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the desired code. Enjoy.

```
$(".btn-block").click(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "Open Form") {
    $(this).text("Submit Form");
    $(this).on("click",callfunction);
} else {
    $(this).text("Open Form");
    $(this).off("click",callfunction);
}
});

function callfunction(){
    alert('ak');
}
```